# MKMapView disable rotation

Tags: ios7, mkmapview

I have an app that uses MKMapView as a main display area. This should always be oriented north-up. But a quick inadvertent swipe and it rotates, cause the compass to appear.

Is there a way to stop this from happening and keep the view locked north? I see a few hints here, but nothing that refers to any sort of built-in mechanism.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW82)?  Doesn't `mapView.rotateEnabled = NO;` work?

Comment: I got all confused by the wording of the camera and such, it wasn't saying what I thought it was saying!

Comment: Yes, by "camera" they mean "point of view".  I think Google uses the same terminology.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A quick look at Apple's documentation on MKMapView:

> rotateEnabled A Boolean value indicating whether the map camera’s
>   heading information is used.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isRotateEnabled) BOOL rotateEnabled
>   Discussion When this property is set to YES and a valid camera is
>   associated with the map, the camera’s heading angle is used to rotate
>   the plane of the map around its center point. When this property is
>   set to NO, the camera’s heading angle is ignored and the map is always
>   oriented so that true north is situated at the top of the map view.

So you could try to set your mapview rotateEnabled property to ´NO´.

[Apple MKMapView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Comment: Interestingly, setting this in the Storyboard didn't work. I had to do it in code in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: RotateEnabled doesn't seem to have any effect on iOS 7.1 for me, it works for iOS 8 though.

Comment: Any solution found for iOS 7.1?